# Multiple scopes in the application using Autofac

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, autofac

I have a question concerning lifetime scopes in Autofac.
It is allowed to create multiple scopes in different places in the application to resolve types?

In official documentation there is such a statement:

> Note: generally speaking, service location is largely considered an anti-pattern **That is, manually creating scopes everywhere and sprinkling use of the container through your code is not necessarily the best way to go**. Using the Autofac integration libraries you usually won’t have to do what we did in the sample app above. Instead, things get resolved from a central, “top level” location in the application and manual resolution is rare. Of course, how you design your app is up to you.

What if I have several view models and I need to resolve some types in each one?

Example:

```
    public class ClassA
    {
        //some code here

    }

    public class ClassB
    {
        //some code here

    }

    public class ClassC
    {
        //some code here

    }

    public class ViewModelA
    {
        public ViewModelA()
        {

        }


        public void Method()
        {
            //some code here
            using (var scope = Container.BeginLifetimeScope())
            {
                var typeC = scope.Resolve<ClassC>();
                //some code here
            }
        }

    }

    public class ViewModelB
    {
        public ViewModelB()
        {

        }

        public void Method()
        {
            //some code here
            using (var scope = Container.BeginLifetimeScope())
            {
                var typeA = scope.Resolve<ClassA>();
                var typeB = scope.Resolve<ClassB>();
                //some code here
            }
        }
    }
```

Assuming that all types are registered in the container - is spreading such scopes across the app is a good practice? How do you understand that?

Best regards.

Comment: `It is allowed to create multiple scopes in different places in the application to resolve types?` Yes.

Comment: `What if I have several view models and I need to resolve some types in each one?` Without a [mcve] it is very hard to visualise your problem.

Comment: Using 
 **var typeA = scope.Resolve<ClassA>();**
 looks like using your container as Service Locator which is [highly debated](https://blog.ploeh.dk/2010/02/03/ServiceLocatorisanAnti-Pattern). I invite you to consider [constructor injection](https://stackify.com/dependency-injection-c-sharp/) instead. And for scope that are shorter then your object lifetime have a look at [factory pattern](https://www.dotnettricks.com/learn/designpatterns/factory-method-design-pattern-dotnet)

Comment: And that is what I wanted to avoid - using container as Service Locator. In that case, how to use Autofac correctly? Probably as you mentioned there is different way to do the job but I just wanted to understand how to use Autofac properly.

Answer (score 0):

TL;DR

> I have a question concerning lifetime scopes in Autofac. It is allowed to create multiple scopes in different places in the application to resolve types?

Yes, it is allowed, even though it *is* considered not the best way to go - but definitely not the prohibited one.

> What if I have several view models and I need to resolve some types in each one?

Just resolve them through constructor injection as it was suggested by @Raymond. You don't need scopes for something as simple as just resolving stuff.

Now, let's talk this through a little bit.

First of all, how do you use constructor injection? There's nothing simpler than that. Let's modify your example just a bit:

```
public class ClassA
{
    //some code here

}

public class ClassB
{
    //some code here

}

public class ClassC
{
    //some code here

}

public class ViewModelA
{
    private ClassC typeC;

    // this is a constructor injection - yes, it's that simple.
    public ViewModelA(ClassC _typeC)
    {
        typeC = _typeC;
    }


    public void Method()
    {
        typeC.doStuff();
    }

}

public class ViewModelB
{
    private ClassA typeA;
    private ClassB typeB;

    public ViewModelB(ClassA _typeA, ClassB _typeB)
    {
        typeA = _typeA;
        typeB = _typeB;
    }

    public void Method()
    {
        typeA.doStuff();
        typeB.doAnotherStuff();
    }
}
```

That's it. You just specify parameters in the constructor and save those parameters somewhere in the private fields of the class - and you're good to go. Just use those objects assuming they do exist for sure. (They can be optional though, but I'll skip that for now). If autofac is unable to resolve some dependency it will throw an exception - thus if your class got created you can be absolutely sure that all the dependencies were resolved and provided to it in the constructor parameters. (Again, I'll skip some more complicated scenarios for the sake of brevity and clarity).

What does it give us? Well, now classes `ViewModelA` and `ViewModelB` know nothing about any containers or DI in general. All they know is that someone (read: "container") will somehow provide a couple of parameters of specified types (which are usually interfaces) from outside. The class itself now knows nothing about who will create its dependencies, where, when and how - it's not its concern anymore. This is the whole point of dependency injection: removing the concern of managing dependencies.

Next thing is - where are the scopes in this picture? Well... nowhere. :) That's the ideal picture: the services are completely unaware of the existence of the DI container.

But what is a lifetime scope anyways? It is a mean of controlling (surprise!) life time of the objects that are resolved from it. You typically don't need it, unless you are dealing with some edge-case scenarios.

Let's take a look at the extremely simplified example. Say, you have some job that needs to perform some kind of requests to external resources on schedule. However, the method that performs requests is actually generic: it does not know beforehand what exact type of request it is performing because it is defined by the type parameter of the method which will only be known in the runtime.

Also, let's say that you have another requirement: you need to not keep api services in the memory but rather create them only for performing the request and then discard them right away after work is done.

It could look something like the following:

```
abstract class SomeSpecialApi<TSomeTypeParam> { // just some common base type
    public abstract string doGetStuff();
}

class SomeSpecialApi1 : SomeSpecialApi<SomeTypeParam1> where SomeTypeParam1 : TSomeTypeParam {

    private HttpClient _client;

    public SomeSpecialApi(HttpClient client) {
        _client = client;
    }

    public override string doGetStuff() {
        return _client.get(someUrlWeDontCareAbout).Result;
    }

}

class SomeSpecialApi2 : SomeSpecialApi<SomeTypeParam2> where SomeTypeParam2 : TSomeTypeParam {

    private SomeFtpClient _client;

    public SomeSpecialApi(SomeFtpClient client) {
        _client = client;
    }

    public override string doGetStuff() {
        // it's just something very different from the previous class
        return _client.read(someOtherPathWeDontCareAboutEither).Result;
    }

}

class JobPerformer {

    private ILifeTimeScope _scope;

    public JobPerformer(ILifeTimeScope scope) {
        _scope = scope;
    }

    void PerformJob<T>() {
        while (true) {
            using (var childScope = scope.BeginLifeTimeScope()) {
                var api = childScope.Resolve<SomeSpecialApi<T>>();
                var result = api.doGetStuff();
                // do something with the result
            } // here the childScope and everything resolved from it will be destroyed
            // and that's the whole purpose of the lifetime scopes.
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
        }
    }

}
```

Do you see how it works? Depending on the method's type parameter container will resolve different classes to get the job done. So, instead of creating all the dependencies and then destroying them manually all you need to do is to create your own scope, request an instance of the service you need and then destroy scope after work is done. Scope destruction takes care of destroying all the dependencies which you don't (and shouldn't) even know about. That's definitely an improvement compared to the creation of all the dependencies manually.

However, the disadvantage here is that now JobPerformer class has to know about such a thing as ILifeTimeScope. So it's in some sense similar to the ServiceLocator pattern: we have to know at least *who* to ask for the dependency, in other words: JobPerformer now knows *something* about our container. That's what we ideally want to avoid, and there are also other means to achieve it: factories; owned instances; different lifetime policies of service registrations in the container; different kinds of lifetime scopes (at least in autofac); etc.